# Info.plist file missing/Unable to set & retrieve CFBundleVersion from my Cocoa project

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I created a new cocoa project using the command-line tool template. I need to be able to set/retrieve the version from the bundle, but the infoDictionary in my mainBundle is only showing three basic items when I do `po [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]`:

```
{ 
    CFBundleExecutablePath = "...";
    NSBundleInitialPath = "...";
    NSBundleResolvePath = "...";
}
```

I do have a Common-Info.plist file, but changing values in here doesn't seem to affect anything. I've also tried to add an Info.plist to my project, but it's ignored.

Is there something special I need to do to get it using the right file?

This is Xcode 3.2.6

**EDIT FOR FIX**

The key was to add this to my 'Other linker flags' option in the target/get info:

`-sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist Info.plist`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed the Info.plist file in a special section of your binary. Daniel Jalkut's blog has some good information on it. Check out the "Embedding Info.plist" section here: http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/2083/the-power-of-plist